# How do I really disable a code analysis rule?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-analysis

I am inundated by the code analysis warning AD0001:

> Analyzer
>   'RefactoringEssentials.CSharp.Diagnostics.FunctionNeverReturnsAnalyzer'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' with message
>   'Specified method is not supported.'

Of course I tried opening project properties (for each of a dozen projects in the solution), going into Code Analysis tab, clicking Open, typing in AD0001, and un-checking the pesky warning. But it is still being thrown in the hundreds.

How can I do it in for good?

Not sure if this is relevant, but I am also getting just 1 instance of

> 'RefactoringEssentials.CSharp.Diagnostics.RedundantBaseQualifierAnalyzer'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' with message
>   'Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Shared.Utilities.AbstractSpeculationAnalyzer`9'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=2.3.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.'.

Answer (score 0):

Argh! Restarting VS is the solution. 456!